# What would an entity relationship diagram look like for a user and a contact list?

Tags: sql, database, entity

If I were trying to create a database for a message service, and I want one entity to be the users, and the other to be the contact list such that each user can see the other users they are connected to (which are the users that are in their contact list) - how would this be done?

I have been racking my brain, but the best I could come up with is that the entities have two relationships: a user can be a part of a contact list (M:N cardinality) and a user can be connected to a contact list (1:1 cardinality). However, I am not sure how I could then map the entity relationship diagram to a logical design.

The thing that confuses me the most is that a contact list *itself* is composed of users, which is another entity. Is there a better way of thinking about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you ware looking for?

```
create table users (
    user_id int generated always as serial primary key,
    . . .  -- additional columns
);

create table user_contacts (
    user_contact_id int generated always as serial primary key,
    user_id int not null references users(user_id),
    contact_id int not null references users(user_id),
    . . .  -- additional columns
    constraint unq_user_contacts_user_contact unique (user_id, contact_id)
);
```

You haven't specified the database, so I have use standard syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not exactly what I was expecting but I can make sense of it (I think; still new to this). So, the idea is to have a table USER_CONTACTS which has an ID as its primary key, a USER ID representing whose contact list it is, and then another column for all the contacts in that list? In this case, won't we have a lot of repetition in the user_id column? Is that ok? Also, if it's not too much to ask, what would the entity relationship diagram that these tables are derived from look like? Thanks again.

Comment: @iaskdumbstuff . . . Each user/contact pair is represented as a separate row.  That is fine.  In fact, that is the SQL way to represent this data.